# Optimizing Server

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, optimization, memcached

Let me lay it all out:

- Lamp environment
- Mysql is already optimized. 
  I've got memcached setup
- I've got APC    setup
- Traffic on these web servers is going to come in hard and    fast,
  its not going to be spread out, think more 10,000 visitors    within
  30 minutes, which isn't too crazy, but these websites do a    whole
  lot of queries.  They're run on ExpressionEngine and are just    very
  processor intensive applications in general.
- Built in EC2    environment.   1 DB server, 1 Web server.  Images and
  static files    are 90% served through cloudfront, so they should be
  a minimal part    of the equation.  Both instances are large
  instances(7.5 GB memory, 4    EC2 Compute units)
- I'm not a server administrator so while I was    able to get all of
  that setup, I'm kind of stuck on what to do to    optimize right now.
  I'm not real impressed with the page load speed    right now

So, knowing how the traffic will flow in and what I've got setup, how do I optimize Apache, memcached, and APC appropriately. And, any other tips? :) Thanks

Comment: Do as EightBitTony suggests below.  There is no magic bullet for performance: You need to load-test your environment, see how it performs, and open up your individual bottlenecks.  Where one environment may be slowed down by a poorly tuned database another may need a PHP accelerator (or a switch to fully-compiled code) to improve performance - it all depends on your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baseline, monitor & measure performance, locate bottleneck, understand cause, make tweak, measure performance.

It's generic, because the problem is generic - unless you know why the page loads are slow you can't solve it - and you don't know until you measure.

Comment: I will do that when the time comes, but, I need to set settings initially.  Knowing the facts that I have stated, what are good basic settings to start off with?

Comment: Also agree with EightBitTony but what exactly do you mean by "Mysql is already optimized"?

Comment: Macgyver - use the default settings it installed with - then, baseline and measure from there.